# Does logistic regression determine the direction of the association?

Tags: logistic, odds-ratio, epidemiology, odds

I've conducted a logistic regression in which a binary outcome was the dependent and some continuous factors were entered as independent variables.

First: Can this model determine that the independent factor will proceed the dependent factor or do we just have associations (since I conducted a case-control study by which I can't determine the causality)?

Second: if the odd ratio is 1.22 of the continuous variable (Biomarker) and the outcome is the binary outcome (vitamin deficiency or obese patient). How can I interpret this results?

Finally, when I entered other risk factors to the model do I interpret the result as dependent and independent risk factor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not taken other steps to ensure that the two factors don't occur in a fixed temporal order, than no, logistic regression will not ensure that that's true.

Your interpretation would be something along the lines of: "A one-unit increase in BIOMARKER increased the odds of vitamin deficiency by 1.22".

> Finally, when I entered other risk factors to the model do I interpret the result as dependent and independent risk factor?

It's a little unclear what you're asking here. The estimates determined in any logistical regression model are conditional on any other variables you've included in the model.

Comment: I'd just add that the interpretation assumes deficiency was coded as 1 and no deficiency was coded as 0.

Comment: But if I interpret the results this way, is it meant that the biomarker is the risk factor for having the vitamin D deficiency, isn't it? In other words, it gives an indication about the direction of the association. Can I say that the biomarker X increased in patients with the outcome (i.e. Vitamin deficiency) by 1.22 as compared with individuals without vitamin defceincy??

Comment: @ReemM.AlHaj If you're interested in then other direction of relationship, why are you using logistic regression?

Comment: @Fomite it's not about direction, but actually, I want to test the independent association between these variables. I have two biomarkers one of them failed to reach the significance level in partial correlation, but when I divided the vitamin deficiency into deficient or not there was a significant difference between the two groups so I conducted logistic regression with 3 different models. indeed, this is my first time with statistics.

Comment: @ReemM.AlHaj Logistic regression is inherently about modeling the response of a binary variable to one or more other variables. While that doesn't necessarily suggest that one causes the other, it's hard to back that exposure out the other direction. I'd suggest, depending on your data, something as simple as an ANOVA if you want to know the level of biomarker as it varies between groups.

Comment: @Fomite if I interpret as you mentioned, does this reflect the dependent and the independent association between the two variables? and thanks for your helpful answer

Comment: @ReemM.AlHaj Could you define what you intend by the "Dependent and independent association between the two variables".

Comment: @Fomite in the crude OR I entered only the dependent (vitamin deficiency or not) and the biomarker. But in the first model, I controlled for several confounders and the OR was  significant so can I say that the odds increase regardless of the confounders (i.e. independently)?

Comment: @ReemM.AlHaj "The odds ratio INCREASED/DECREASED upon adjustment for potential confounders". The effect measure is more important than the statistical significance, IMO. If you must, then "The odds ratio was statistically significant after several potential confounders were adjusted for."